# In for Loop, inside GCD, pause, get input, continue

Tags: objective-c, performance, for-loop, objective-c-blocks, grand-central-dispatch

I want to know if there was a way to break away from gcd, show in input alert view and then return to the process? THis was my normal routine:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_LOW, 0), ^{


    NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray new];
    for(NSIndexPath * ip in [self.tableView indexPathsForSelectedRows]){
        [array addObject:[CompanyObjectsArray objectAtIndex:ip.row]];
    }
    //I need to check for a an Object here, if present get input from User.
    [self addCompaniesOrCreate:[NSArray arrayWithArray:array]];



    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    });
});
```

I add all objects into core data like that,

But I had a need where'd if a company is "Appl3" , i should get an input from the User, and if i get it, continue and loop with the rest, or else skip the current "Appl3" company.

Is there a way i could do this efficiently, **while in the for() loop, pause, get input, continue the for() loop**.

thanks for the help guys :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such way I am aware of. The usual pattern would be to write your own method that takes a block as a completion handler. So basically you pass back to the main thread the block that you want to run when you've got your user input you wanted.

Best regards,

sven.